# Browser caching by Windows clients is generating huge I/O to server

Tags: windows, networking, group-policy, cache, network-attached-storage

In our environment, our users have their `My Documents` folder stored on an ENC NAS device. I have noticed huge traffic coming from our isers machines, and I see that most of it is coming to cache directories of Internet Explorer and other browsers.

We have various Windows clients and no restrictions on browsers. Is there any way to prevetn this traffic from hitting our NAS by way of a group policy or something similar?

Comment: From what I remember, the IE cache directories are not stored under MyDocuments, but in the AppData directory. Are the AppData directories on your NAS as well?

Comment: AppData is under the user's folder, so depending on the configuration of his folder redirection, it could be redirecting the AppData folder as well (ick!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is, and in the general case, I advice against redirecting the `AppData` folder for this very reason, though sometimes there is a pressing need to redirect it.

The Group Policy setting you want is located at `User Configuration\Windows Settings\Folder Redirection\Application Data`

Assuming it's currently set to redirect, and you want to send it back to the local machine, you'll want to make sure to go to the Settings tab and hit the radio button is set to "Redirect the folder back to the local userprofile location when the policy is removed."  (Note that users must log off and log back or on for folder redirection settings to take effect.)

[Here's a link to the relevant Microsoft instructions, which work for Windows 2000 and up](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888203/en-us).